# Untrusted application using Xubuntu 16

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, linux

I get this warning when trying to launch the start-tor-browser.desktop
from Xubuntu 16.
I've tried Marking as Executable and Launch Anyway options and am prevented from ticking the Allow to run as an executable in the Permissions properties box.
Can anyone throw any light on this, please.
I would just add that I was unable to verify the package with the key.
I made a mess of trying to do that.
Thanks,
Bob F.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would just add that I was unable to verify the package with the key.

If the package was not verified, there is no way to be sure this is actually the Tor browser.  I'd suggest starting over and this time:

1. [Download the Tor browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) and the appropriate signature file (same page).
2. [Verify the signature](https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en) using the [developer's PGP key](https://www.torproject.org/docs/signing-keys.html.en).
3. [Expand the tar file and run the program](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#linux).

If you are going to use Tor, it makes sense to do it right.